# iOS - How to decode image with zxing

Tags: ios, image, decode, qr-code, zxing

I need to decode an QR image using the zxing library for iOS.

I'm new to iOS programming, and have been looking through the code examples included in the project, but I can't figure out how to just decode an image using this library.

If anyone can please post examples of how I decode an image it would be much appreciated.

So far I've identified the Decoder class, which has a method called "decodeImage" which I've loaded with an image. But this method returns a boolean, and what I need is a text string containing the value of the QR code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was the code that finally solved my problem - thanks to the help from smparkes

### HEADER FILE

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ApplicationConfiguration.h"
#import <ZXingWidgetController.h> 

@interface ScanViewController : UIViewController<DecoderDelegate>
{
    UIButton *scanButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *scanButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain ) NSSet *readers;

- (IBAction)doScanAction;
- (void)decoder:(Decoder *)decoder didDecodeImage:(UIImage *)image usingSubset:(UIImage *)subset withResult:(TwoDDecoderResult *)result;
- (void)decoder:(Decoder *)decoder failedToDecodeImage:(UIImage *)image usingSubset:(UIImage *)subset reason:(NSString *)reason;

@end
```

### IMPLEMENTATION FILE

```
#import "ScanViewController.h"
#import <ZXingWidgetController.h> 
#import <QRCodeReader.h> 
#import "TwoDDecoderResult.h"

@implementation ScanViewController

@synthesize scanButton;
@synthesize readers;

-(IBAction)doScanAction{
    QRCodeReader* qrcodeReader = [[QRCodeReader alloc] init];
    self.readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:qrcodeReader,nil];
    [qrcodeReader release];

    Decoder *d = [[Decoder alloc] init];
    [d setDelegate:self];
    [d setReaders:self.readers];
    [readers retain];

    BOOL decodeSuccess= [d decodeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"QRcode.png"]];
    NSLog(@"BOOL = %@\n", (decodeSuccess ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
}

- (void)decoder:(Decoder *)decoder didDecodeImage:(UIImage *)image usingSubset:(UIImage *)subset withResult:(TwoDDecoderResult *)result{
    [result retain];
    NSLog(@"Did Decode Image Result: %d",[result text]);
    [result release];
}

- (void)decoder:(Decoder *)decoder failedToDecodeImage:(UIImage *)image usingSubset:(UIImage *)subset reason:(NSString *)reason;
{
    [reason retain];
    NSLog(@"Failed Decode Image Result: %d",reason);
    [reason release];
}

@end
```

Comment: Congrats on the solution!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark to the left.  This will enable others to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a delegate class/instance and set the decoder `delegate` property. Then the widget will call `didDecodeImage` or `failedToDecodeImage` when you call `decodeImage`.

Comment: So basically I can let my controller implement the "DecodeDelegate" class like this: "... : UIViewController<DecoderDelegate>". 
And in my controller instantiate my Decoder object like this: Decoder *d = [[Decoder alloc] init];  
followed by assigning the delegate to the decoder with [d.delegate self ]; 
Correct?

Comment: Your assignment syntax is wrong: d.delegate = self; or [d setDelegate:self]; You also may need to configure the readers. The ZXWidgetController does this so it should server as a guide.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! This was very helpful. Now I'm not a long time member in here - but I hope what I'm doing by posting the solution that worked for me, is OK?